# Load jQuery first in 'head' tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal

I have a widget that I've embedded in my Squarespace website on multiple pages. It uses jQuery, but it's not working each time it loads because I haven't loaded jQuery first (I think). I know PayPal loads jQuery as a dependency.  I'm trying to solve this by injecting code into the 'head' tag on each page of my site (there's an easy way to do this on Squarespace). However, I'm unsure how to code this. Thanks!

Code on each page:
https://jsfiddle.net/nsilverblatt/y26nfq6v/

jQuery code that looks relevant (I'm new to this):

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/eboxapps/js/5c/e55b8dad5c8ac1fc2d31f92f0dc3e810b7df96.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/eboxapps/js/73/476f06e3db7705e4f9a56a016f80df1973fc84.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/tagmgmt/bs.js" async="" defer=""></script>
<script src="//www.paypalobjects.com/js/site_catalyst/pp_jscode_080706.js"></script>
```

The actual website that is not loading the new PayPal tab correctly when you try to donate (unless you refresh a specific charity page): https://www.dailydonate.org

Comment: jQuery v1.11.2 is already being included in minified JS `https://www.paypalobjects.com/eboxapps/js/5c/e55b8dad5c8ac1fc2d31f92f0dc3e810b7df96.js`. Hence you don't need to inject jQuery separately. Some thing else should be the problem. Please investigate in browser console panel.

Comment: The error is Uncaught ReferenceError: calcDonation is not defined

Comment: Please clear the syntax errors in this page using [validator.w3.org]. For ex: form with `id="cashDonation"` whose onsubmit attributes value should be in quotes `onsubmit=return submitDonation();`. These syntax errors can break the following script tag which contains `calcDonation` function called by clicking radio button.

Comment: This didn't fix the problem; 'Uncaught ReferenceError: calcDonation is not defined' still shows up here jsfiddle.net/nsilverblatt/zo4st8n9/